# What's the relationship between smart contract and NFT collections?

Tags: nft

I am new to web3 and block chain. I have learned that NFTs are just the tokens stored in a smart contract. But then I see another concept -- NFT Collections. I really wonder what's the relationship between them. Is a contract and a collection one-to-one correspondence or anything else

Answer (score 0):

As you know NFTs are just ERC-721 token, as single NFT token stored in NFT contract same like more than one token also stored in contract also. You can check your balance of tokens by "**balanceOf**" method. these tokens can be stored in Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

This is just terminology and it varies a bit. An NFT Collection means all of the NFTs which are inside one contract. I guess "collection" is a sexier term than "contract".